# Can "no-fault" be used as a noun?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, nouns, adjectives

All outputs from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/no-fault), [Merriem Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no-fault) and others like [oxforddictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/no-fault) state it as an adjective. My question is can it be used as a noun? If yes, could you provide examples?

Comment: A motor vehicle insurance company, who attribute faults all day, perhaps shorten "it is a no-fault insurance claim" to "it's a no-fault".

Answer (score 2):

**no-fault** as a noun:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/127627?redirectedFrom=no%20fault#eid)

> Insurance. No-fault insurance.

As in:

> 1994   Star-Ledger (Newark, New Jersey) 24 Apr.  Rising rates was only
>   one of the horrors faced by motorists before n**o-fault**.

and

> 1984   Best's Rev. (Property–Casualty Insurance ed.) (Nexis) Dec. 22
>   Prior to **no-fault**, every motorist was required to carry $20,000 of
>   tort liability insurance.

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/no%20fault%20insurance) has the following as a noun:

**no fault insurance**

> n a system of automobile insurance where a party who is injured in an
>   automobile accident recovers damages up to a specific amount against
>   his own insurance company regardless of who was responsible for the
>   accident

The Free Dictionary also has the noun.

Comment: Great! can you provide more examples please? I'm unable to access the OED and I need to comprehend its use as a noun further. Does it only mean "insurance"?

Comment: [New Jersey is known for mandating no-fault car insurance](https://www.myinjuryattorney.com/new-jersey-car-accident-lawyer/no-fault-insurance/), hence references could refer either to the individual insurance policies or to the wider system of no-fault car insurance.